# PHP struggling to parse some XML

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I am calling some webservices and then pulling the data from the XML responses. Most are fine but one of the services allows me to execute some SQL to retrieve additional data, and the layout of this response is very different to the others. I can't amend the services so just need to know how to get at the data;

```
The data I am getting back is as follows, from a

 Print_r;
```

stdClass Object ( [schema] => stdClass Object ( [element] => stdClass Object ( [complexType] => stdClass Object ( [choice] => stdClass Object ( [element] => stdClass Object ( [complexType] => stdClass Object ( [sequence] => stdClass Object ( [element] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [simpleType] => stdClass Object ( [restriction] => stdClass Object ( [maxLength] => ) ) ) [1] => [2] => stdClass Object ( [simpleType] => stdClass Object ( [restriction] => stdClass Object ( [maxLength] => ) ) ) [3] => [4] => [5] => stdClass Object ( [simpleType] => stdClass Object ( [restriction] => stdClass Object ( [maxLength] => ) ) ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [simpleType] => stdClass Object ( [restriction] => stdClass Object ( [maxLength] => ) ) ) [7] => [8] => stdClass Object ( [simpleType] => stdClass Object ( [restriction] => stdClass Object ( [maxLength] => ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) [diffgram] => stdClass Object ( [VTSData] => stdClass Object ( [Table] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [PreferredFieldManagerID] => L005 [Priority] => 1 [AreaOfExpertiseID] => 1 [X] => 72958 [Y] => 5225329 [District] => P.O. BOX 15 [Agent] => FLS-AUTO-UPLOAD [Condition] => 0 [EquipmentName] => 11/02/2016 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [PreferredFieldManagerID] => L005 [Priority] => 1 [AreaOfExpertiseID] => 1 [X] => 72958 [Y] => 5225329 [District] => P.O. BOX 15 [Condition] => 0 [EquipmentName] => 11/02/2016 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [PreferredFieldManagerID] => L005 [Priority] => 1 [AreaOfExpertiseID] => 1 [X] => 72958 [Y] => 5225329 [District] => P.O. BOX 15 [Condition] => 0 [EquipmentName] => 11/02/2016 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [PreferredFieldManagerID] => L005 [Priority] => 1 [AreaOfExpertiseID] => 1 [X] => 72958 [Y] => 5225329 [District] => P.O. BOX 15 [Condition] => 0 [EquipmentName] => 11/02/2016 ) ) ) ) )

and the elements I need are the ones called [X], [Y], [AreaofExpertiseId] etc...
    Tried

```
 echo($result -> AreaOfExpertiseID);
    echo($result -> X);
    echo($result -> Y);
```

etc...which syntax works for my other resulting XMLs ...

but these fail with

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$AreaOfExpertiseID in ...etc...
```

Please can anyone help?

Phil

Comment: that response isn't xml, can you post the actual response rather than what you get from print_r

Comment: as you can see you have nested objects which means you need to do like this : $result->object1->object->......object->X;

Answer (score 0):

If that `print_r` you are showing is the contents of `$result` then the data you need is at

```
$result->diffgram->VTSData->Table
```

This will be an array of objects, which you can iterate over and get what you're looking for.

```
$table = $result->diffgram->VTSData->Table;
foreach ($table as $item) {
    echo $item->AreaOfExpertiseID, $item->X, $item->Y;
    // or whatever you need to do with them
}
```